# How to convert Pandas Series to show the date time with PDT instead of PST timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timezone

I want to convert the pandas Series object to PDT time instead of PST time.Currently the conversion shows like

```
df.datetime.dt.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
```

shows like (PST time -7:00)

```
2019-05-19 21:59:00-07:00
```

But I want it to be shown like (PDT time -8:00)

```
2019-05-19 21:59:00-08:00
```

I already tried with ambiguous and other options but its not changing the data.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
df.datetime.dt.tz_localize('America/Los_Angeles')
```

Ref: [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Yes. same result

Answer (score 0):

`tz_localize` is doing the correct thing.  It's your expectation that is incorrect.

- Pacific Standard Time (PST) is UTC-8, or `-08:00`.
- Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) is UTC-7, or `-07:00`.

[Reference Here.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles)

Comment: Correct. For the date you gave in May, PDT applies, which is -07:00.